# Pycaret : "AttributeError: 'Simple_Imputer' object has no attribute 'target_variable'"

Tags: python, conda, pycaret

I've created a clean conda enviroment with Python 3.7:

`conda create -n pycaret python=3.7`

Then I installed pycaret:

`pip install pycaret[full]`

I opened jupyter Notebook from the conda prompt, and followed the first tutorial from here: https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/blob/master/examples/PyCaret%202%20Classification.ipynb

But when I run this block:

```
from pycaret.classification import *
clf1 = setup(data, target = 'Purchase', session_id=123, log_experiment=True, experiment_name='juice1')
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Simple_Imputer' object has no attribute 'target_variable'
```

What's happening? I tried different installations, different python versions, but always got the same error.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with pycaret. Still not solved... I am also getting crazy with this error.

I wanted to try pycaret but I will have to wait until the error is fixed. I just created a new virtual environment, executed pip install pycaret and run the example...

Even the example is not working anymore. Many people are facing the same problem. I hope it will be solved soon...

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem many times and the installation of version 0.23.2 of scikit-learn always did the trick on my side.

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.23.2 --force-reinstall
```

I found the trick a while ago [here](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/issues/823#issuecomment-817309828).